# Standard way to reverse a motor?

Tags: dc-motor

Is using a relay and some switches a standard way to reverse a motor or is the preferred method to use a H-Bridge? The circuit for reversing a motor with a relay looks like this:
[image: Circuit]

Note that this circuit is just to show the relay and motor connections. The main control would be the coming from a PIC not an op-amp.

Me and my teacher are having disagreements about the best way/standard/preferred way to reverse motors, so what would engineers do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever I have done motor control it has been with an H-Bridge.  But the ideal solution depends on several factors:

What is the voltage/current required?  For <24 volts and <5 amps, an H-Bridge is normally the preferred solution.  The reason for this is the MOSFET's that can handle those voltages/currents are easy to get, easy to design with, and fairly inexpensive.

Is speed control, dynamic breaking, or regenerative breaking required?  If so, an H-Bridge is again usually the best.

But in the case where there is no speed control, and the frequency of "direction reversals" is low, and/or the voltage/current is very high then a relay could be a good choice.

The main selling point of the relay is its simplicity and ease of use.  An H-Bridge will always perform better but it is harder to design, sometimes can be more expensive, and adds complexity that is not always required.

Answer (score 1):

How about the best of both, use a relay to switch the motor direction and a power device to control the speed of the motor (It's how early speed controllers worked - it was a lot cheaper to just have a single power stage, and a relay could switch easily - you just need to make sure the motor is going slowly when switching to avoid arcing in the relay)

So 1 pin would control the motor and 1 PWM output run a power stage to control the speed.

(A power stage could be a simple as a resistor, a transistor and a reverse protection diode)

Comment: Here's a circuit that does exactly that: http://www.siliconchip.com.au/cms/A_112070/article.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are switching a lot of current, a relay is cheaper (especially in the old days when high power transistors cost a lot more!), a H-bridge has the advantage of PWM speed control, and  instant reversal.

For small currents, (<2A) a single chip H-bridge is economical and more compact.   For heavy duty high current motors, the reverse is true, a relay will be cheaper and smaller than a high-power H-bridge.

If you don't need electronic speed control, and aren't changing direction zillions of times an hour, a relay is a fine solution, and a heckload easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get speed control with an H-bridge. They are popular because of that.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Yes I say H-bridge and that relays are a non standard way. He's all for the relays.