# Alternative way to control a DC motor with an ATMega328P and external power

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, dc-motor

I am designing a PCB to control a DC Motor's direction with an ATMega328P microcontroller.  The output isn't enough for the DC motor so I used a TIP120 but now I can't control the way the motor is rotating.  Is there a better way of doing that or using a different component?

[image]

The code for the Arduino in the picture is:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
}
```

Comment: @JYelton Just did it....

Comment: See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/12551/2028

Answer (score 1):

A H-bridge can be used to control the direction of a DC motor. Taking the example of the [Arduino Motor Shield Rev3](https://store.arduino.cc/products/arduino-motor-shield-rev3?selectedStore=eu):

> The Arduino Motor Shield is based on the L298 ([datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/sense_power/FM142/CL851/SC1790/SS1555/PF63147)), which is a dual full-bridge driver designed to drive inductive loads such as relays, solenoids, DC and stepping motors. It lets you drive two DC motors with your Arduino board, controlling the speed and **direction** of each one independently.

Comment: It is too large for my project, I have it i also have the L293D Motor Driver IC, Do you think that'd be useful?

Comment: @Aland What is the current consumption of your DC motor? Do you have a link to the datasheet to the DC motor?

Comment: @Aland [Problems with L293, L298 and SN754410 H-bridge drivers on a low voltage supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/problems-with-l293-l298-and-sn754410-h-bridge-drivers-on-a-low-voltage-supply)